# Javascript countdown does not show in Opera mini

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, opera-mini

So i have this countdown script, which is works just fine almost every browser but not in opera mini. It shows a blank space.
Here is my code:

```
timer={
times:[],
init:false,
callback:function() { window.location.reload(); },
new:function(time)
{
    timer.times[timer.times.length]=time;
    document.write("<span id='timer_"+(timer.times.length-1)+"'>"+timer.format(time)+"</span>");
    timer.start();
},
format:function(time)
{
    days=Math.floor(time/(60*60*24));
    hours=Math.floor(time%(60*60*24)/(60*60));
    mins=Math.floor(time%(60*60)/60);
    secs=Math.floor(time%60);
    return (mins<10?"0":"")+mins+":"+(secs<10?"0":"")+secs+"";
},
ticker:function()
{
    for(var i=0; i<timer.times.length; i++)
    {
        if(timer.times[i] == 0) { timer.callback(); break; }
        document.getElementById("timer_"+i).innerHTML=timer.format(timer.times[i]);
        timer.times[i]--;
    }
},
start:function()
{
    if(!timer.init)
    {
        timer.init=true;
        setInterval(timer.ticker, 1000);
    }
}
}
```

Is there a problem with the code?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Side note of warning: Using `new` (or any other reserved word) as a *literal* property name won't work in some older browsers (IE8, for instance). It used to be invalid syntax (ES3) and was only made valid in ES5. So for instance, `var obj = {new: "test"};` will fail in IE8, as will `console.log(obj.new);` You can, however, use the string literal form and bracketed notation: `var obj = {"new": "test"};` and `console.log(obj["new"]);` Examples: [Fails](http://jsbin.com/hugamape/1) - [Works](http://jsbin.com/hugamape/2).

Answer (score 0):

Just check your code for errors in `opera mini` console. Open your page in `opera mini` and write in address bar this:

```
server:console?post=http://path_to_your_page
```

Also, `Opera Mini` has javascript timers limits - it stops any timers after 2-5 seconds (depend from `Opera Mini` version). On my Android timer stops after 5 seconds([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/LhGqb/show)).

Answer (score 0):

Timers work differently in operamini, Read https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/

Copied from the above link,
Code registered with setTimeout() and setInterval() may be run before the page is sent, but it is unlikely that it will be called more than once because of script pausing